# I need help finding questions that have a similar to theme to what I am thinking of (juggling a part time job with a research position)

Tags: discussion

**I need to juggle a part-time programming job, along with a research position.** Why? Well, because my research position doesn't pay much, and I have a lot of (student) debt to cover. I have only recently begun to "bloom" academically, so I don't have the history of performance required for a compelling scholarship application just yet either.

**I am having trouble switching between "work" and "research".** Going from "research" to "work" is pretty easy and painless, because work requires almost no "mental preparation". I put mental preparation in quotation marks because I am not sure if it's something that exists, but to me it seems that the longer I have been immersed in a "research phase", the more productive I seem to become. My mental picture of the problem gets clearer in my mind and grows organically the longer I have been immersed in the "research phase", naturally letting me understand what I have to learn/do next. Switching to work-mode disrupts this mental picture, and I have to spend time re-building it when going back to research, which leads to *lots* of procrastination. There isn't a comparable mental preparation state when it comes to doing my job. Thus, going from "work" to "research" is not so easy, while going from "research" to "work" is painless. **It also seems like work doesn't give me the time to "mope" when research isn't going well -- and I have come to value seemingly unproductive, semi-self-hating moping sessions, because they allow me to suss out what it is I am unhappy with in my current approach.**

---

**How has this problem been dealt with (successfully, or unsuccessfully) by others?** I am having trouble finding questions which seem to address this directly, but perhaps I am just tired today and my search-fu is not up to par. In any case, I am sure many questions with such a theme have been asked...

Could you help lead a horse to water?

Comment: One question that is similar in theme: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8747/is-it-possible-to-work-full-time-and-complete-a-phd/8762#8762

Comment: Why is this question in meta? It seems to be just a regular SE question (*sans* the "help me find similar questions" part of the title).